# Python: using subprocess to stream data without deadlocks?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a little script for shuffling a lot of data around. It's something like this:

```
outproc = None
for input in input_files:
    p = Popen('process_input "%s" | more_input_processing' %(input, ),
              shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    for line in p.stdout.xreadlines():
        if linecount % 1000000 == 0:
            outfile = "output%03d" %(linecount // 1000000, )
            if outproc:
                outproc.stdin.close()
                result = outproc.wait() # <-- deadlock here
                assert result == 0, "outproc exited with %s" %(result, )
            outproc = Popen('handle_output "%s"' %(outfile, ),
                            shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
        linecount += 1
        outproc.stdin.write(line)
    p.stdout.close()
    result = p.wait()
    assert result == 0, "p exited with %s" %(result, )
```

As the documentation warns, though, I'm hitting a deadlock when I try to wait for `outproc` (see comment).

The “solution” proposed by the documentation is to use `.communicate()`… But doing that would involve reading all the input into memory before flushing it, which is undesirable.

So, how can I stream data between subprocesses without deadlocks?

Comment: Alright, so if I don't actually wait on the subprocess (ie, remove all the calls to `.wait()`), everything appears to work, and that's fine for this script (it's just a one-off). It would be nice if I could figure out how to make it work properly, though…

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `close` on a pipe the subprocess actually reads, so it won't receive SIGPIPE or anything to cause it to exit. Just kill the process when you have enough data. Alternatively, pipe both input and output and use select to know when you should read or write.

Comment: What do you mean, “not using `close` on a pipe the subprocess reads”? The `handle_output` script is constantly reading from stdin… So when I `outproc.stdin.close()`, doesn't that close a pipe it's reading from?

Comment: The subprocess's stdin isn't a pipe your process opened itself; it opened a file from its command line args and you can't close it on its behalf.

Comment: Hrm. Alright… But just killing the process isn't good enough either: it expects to do some cleanup (a database commit) after it's finished reading from stdin (and if it's killed that doesn't happen).